# Neopixel matrix with holes

Tags: arduino, adafruit, neopixel

I want to create a wearable LED Matrix face mask out of Neopixel LED stripes. However I need to compensate add holes for my eyes. How can I add holes in a matrix with the `Adafruit_NeoMatrix` Arduino Library.

Here is my matrix, 1 represents an LED, 0 represents a missing LED.
I use a zigzag pattern starting from the top right moving from right to left, then down, then left to right and so on...

```
    [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ]
```

I thought I could somehow use this array as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **FastLED library** found [here](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) and [read](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Basic-usage) how to switch LEDs on or off and then use the basic approach below.

```
uint8_t myPattern[] = {1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23,24,25,71,72,73,74,75}; // 15 LEDs ("pixels")

myPatternLength = 15;

for(uint8_t i=0; i < myPatternLength ; i++)
{
  leds[myPattern[i]] = CHSV(255,255,255); // The 15 LEDs ("pixels") will be white
}

FastLED.show();
```